# how to distinguish between"would" and" to be to"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

About Magellan: He married the daughter of Diogo Barbosa. He had two daughters from her, both of whom died at a young age. **She would die in Seville around 1521.**

Have I correctly rephrased the bold part?

And, in this story or narrative, She was to die in Seville around 1521.

The best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct, but I would not use it in my writing. When writing about historical events, it is traditional to keep detached, and use a simple past tense the whole way through. "She died in Seville circa 1521." (Circa is Latin for near, and is commonly used by historians for uncertain and approximate dates. It can be abbreviated "ca.")

This practice doesn't make for exciting reading, but it keeps respect for past events, and is what most readers expect. Your phrasing seems sensational somehow, it draws the reader back into a timeframe where she hasn't already died just in time for her to die. It brings to mind the question of "what if she hadn't died there?"